# Problem with using remote desktop application via citrix web client

Tags: gnome, remote-desktop, citrix

I have problem when I connect to remote desktop (Windows VDI) via Citrix application from web, it look like that mouse hot spot is shifted to upper position then I can't click on the correct button or menu items, when I'd like to click to title bar I always get at gnome bar which is not my intention.

In my understanding it might be from position mapping between gnome and remote desktop may not fit together. Am I correct ? should it be considered as bug for gnome or Citrix side?

Do you guy have some experience the similar problem, is there any solution?

My Ubuntu is 12.04 and my Citrix client is 12.1.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem many times.  I find that if i take the app out of fullscreen mode the problem goes away.  So don't maximize the window, just make it as big as you can unmaximized.